# What is the appropriate conv_filter specifications for custom observation_space?

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, ray

I'm trying to create a custom openai gym environment for use in a ray reinforcement learning environment.

Currently I have an observation space of (6, 94). However, when I attempt to train in my custom env, I get the error:

````
```
ValueError: No default configuration for obs shape [6, 94], you must specify `conv_filters` manually as a model option. Default configurations are only available for inputs of shape [42, 42, K] and [84, 84, K]. You may alternatively want to use a custom model or preprocessor.
```
````

The documentation reads:

````
```  Note that you’ll probably have to configure conv_filters if your environment observations have custom sizes, e.g.,"model":  {"dim":  42, "conv_filters":  [[16, [4, 4], 2], [32, [4,4], 2], [512, [11, 11], 1]]}for 42x42 observations.```
````

It's not specific on what exactly is meant to be implemented nor is there any link to literature which specifies what "model" and "conv_filters" are supposed to be doing.

For the (6,94) case, is the "dim" supposed to be 6 or 94? Is the conv_filters fine leaving as is, or is a certain network architecture necessary for each shape? If so, where is the link?

```
2019-07-22 12:52:30,562 INFO node.py:498 -- Process STDOUT and STDERR is being redirected to /tmp/ray/session_2019-07-22_12-52-30_528225_14/logs.
2019-07-22 12:52:31,285 INFO services.py:409 -- Waiting for redis server at 127.0.0.1:47266 to respond...
2019-07-22 12:52:31,650 INFO services.py:409 -- Waiting for redis server at 127.0.0.1:56261 to respond...
2019-07-22 12:52:31,655 INFO services.py:806 -- Starting Redis shard with 3.42 GB max memory.
2019-07-22 12:52:32,488 INFO node.py:512 -- Process STDOUT and STDERR is being redirected to /tmp/ray/session_2019-07-22_12-52-30_528225_14/logs.
2019-07-22 12:52:32,493 INFO services.py:1446 -- Starting the Plasma object store with 5.13 GB memory using /dev/shm.
W0722 12:52:47.568245 140718767867648 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/tune/logger.py:136: The name tf.VERSION is deprecated. Please use tf.version.VERSION instead.

W0722 12:52:47.570142 140718767867648 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/tune/logger.py:141: The name tf.summary.FileWriter is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter instead.

2019-07-22 12:52:49,538 WARNING ppo.py:151 -- FYI: By default, the value function will not share layers with the policy model ('vf_share_layers': False).
2019-07-22 12:52:54,630 INFO rollout_worker.py:301 -- Creating policy evaluation worker 0 on CPU (please ignore any CUDA init errors)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-8da763475e1e> in <module>
     23              }
     24     #resources = PPOTrainer.default_resource_request(config).to_json()
---> 25     trainer = PPOTrainer(env = my_env, config = config)
     26     for _ in range(10):
     27         result = trainer.train()

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/rllib/agents/trainer_template.py in __init__(self, config, env, logger_creator)
     85 
     86         def __init__(self, config=None, env=None, logger_creator=None):
---> 87             Trainer.__init__(self, config, env, logger_creator)
     88 
     89         def _init(self, config, env_creator):

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/rllib/agents/trainer.py in __init__(self, config, env, logger_creator)
    321             logger_creator = default_logger_creator
    322 
--> 323         Trainable.__init__(self, config, logger_creator)
    324 
    325     @classmethod

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/tune/trainable.py in __init__(self, config, logger_creator)
     85         self._iterations_since_restore = 0
     86         self._restored = False
---> 87         self._setup(copy.deepcopy(self.config))
     88         self._local_ip = ray.services.get_node_ip_address()
     89 

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/rllib/agents/trainer.py in _setup(self, config)
    436 
    437         with get_scope():
--> 438             self._init(self.config, self.env_creator)
    439 
    440             # Evaluation related

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/rllib/agents/trainer_template.py in _init(self, config, env_creator)
    104             else:
    105                 self.workers = self._make_workers(env_creator, policy, config,
--> 106                                                   self.config["num_workers"])
    107             if make_policy_optimizer:
    108                 self.optimizer = make_policy_optimizer(self.workers, config)

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/rllib/agents/trainer.py in _make_workers(self, env_creator, policy, config, num_workers)
    481             config,
    482             num_workers=num_workers,
--> 483             logdir=self.logdir)
    484 
    485     @DeveloperAPI

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/rllib/evaluation/worker_set.py in __init__(self, env_creator, policy, trainer_config, num_workers, logdir, _setup)
     62             # Always create a local worker
     63             self._local_worker = self._make_worker(
---> 64                 RolloutWorker, env_creator, policy, 0, self._local_config)
     65 
     66             # Create a number of remote workers

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/rllib/evaluation/worker_set.py in _make_worker(self, cls, env_creator, policy, worker_index, config)
    212             remote_env_batch_wait_ms=config["remote_env_batch_wait_ms"],
    213             soft_horizon=config["soft_horizon"],
--> 214             _fake_sampler=config.get("_fake_sampler", False))

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/rllib/evaluation/rollout_worker.py in __init__(self, env_creator, policy, policy_mapping_fn, policies_to_train, tf_session_creator, batch_steps, batch_mode, episode_horizon, preprocessor_pref, sample_async, compress_observations, num_envs, observation_filter, clip_rewards, clip_actions, env_config, model_config, policy_config, worker_index, monitor_path, log_dir, log_level, callbacks, input_creator, input_evaluation, output_creator, remote_worker_envs, remote_env_batch_wait_ms, soft_horizon, _fake_sampler)
    309                 with self.tf_sess.as_default():
    310                     self.policy_map, self.preprocessors = \
--> 311                         self._build_policy_map(policy_dict, policy_config)
    312         else:
    313             self.policy_map, self.preprocessors = self._build_policy_map(

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/rllib/evaluation/rollout_worker.py in _build_policy_map(self, policy_dict, policy_config)
    713             if tf:
    714                 with tf.variable_scope(name):
--> 715                     policy_map[name] = cls(obs_space, act_space, merged_conf)
    716             else:
    717                 policy_map[name] = cls(obs_space, act_space, merged_conf)

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/rllib/policy/tf_policy_template.py in __init__(self, obs_space, action_space, config, existing_inputs)
    126                 make_action_sampler=make_action_sampler,
    127                 existing_inputs=existing_inputs,
--> 128                 obs_include_prev_action_reward=obs_include_prev_action_reward)
    129 
    130             if after_init:

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/rllib/policy/dynamic_tf_policy.py in __init__(self, obs_space, action_space, config, loss_fn, stats_fn, update_ops_fn, grad_stats_fn, before_loss_init, make_action_sampler, existing_inputs, get_batch_divisibility_req, obs_include_prev_action_reward)
    137                 self.config["model"],
    138                 state_in=existing_state_in,
--> 139                 seq_lens=existing_seq_lens)
    140             self.action_dist = self.dist_class(self.model.outputs)
    141             action_sampler = self.action_dist.sample()

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/rllib/models/catalog.py in get_model(input_dict, obs_space, action_space, num_outputs, options, state_in, seq_lens)
    226         model = ModelCatalog._get_model(input_dict, obs_space, action_space,
    227                                         num_outputs, options, state_in,
--> 228                                         seq_lens)
    229 
    230         if options.get("use_lstm"):

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/rllib/models/catalog.py in _get_model(input_dict, obs_space, action_space, num_outputs, options, state_in, seq_lens)
    263         if obs_rank > 1:
    264             return VisionNetwork(input_dict, obs_space, action_space,
--> 265                                  num_outputs, options)
    266 
    267         return FullyConnectedNetwork(input_dict, obs_space, action_space,

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/rllib/models/model.py in __init__(self, input_dict, obs_space, action_space, num_outputs, options, state_in, seq_lens)
     83                 input_dict["obs"], obs_space)
     84             self.outputs, self.last_layer = self._build_layers_v2(
---> 85                 restored, num_outputs, options)
     86         except NotImplementedError:
     87             self.outputs, self.last_layer = self._build_layers(

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/rllib/models/visionnet.py in _build_layers_v2(self, input_dict, num_outputs, options)
     19         filters = options.get("conv_filters")
     20         if not filters:
---> 21             filters = _get_filter_config(inputs.shape.as_list()[1:])
     22 
     23         activation = get_activation_fn(options.get("conv_activation"))

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/rllib/models/visionnet.py in _get_filter_config(shape)
     70         raise ValueError(
     71             "No default configuration for obs shape {}".format(shape) +
---> 72             ", you must specify `conv_filters` manually as a model option. "
     73             "Default configurations are only available for inputs of shape "
     74             "[42, 42, K] and [84, 84, K]. You may alternatively want "

ValueError: No default configuration for obs shape [6, 94], you must specify `conv_filters` manually as a model option. Default configurations are only available for inputs of shape [42, 42, K] and [84, 84, K]. You may alternatively want to use a custom model or preprocessor.
```

Edit: It turns out it wants the parameters to a CNN, now trying to adjust the values so it comes out to the desired output space.

Edit 2:

The catalog provided on the github isn't up to date with 0.7.2:

https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/rllib/models/catalog.py

```
Unknown config key `no_final_linear`, all keys: ['free_log_std', 'grayscale', 'framestack', 'conv_activation', 'squash_to_range', 'zero_mean', 'custom_model', 'fcnet_activation', 'custom_options', 'conv_filters', 'fcnet_hiddens', 'lstm_use_prev_action_reward', 'custom_preprocessor', 'max_seq_len', 'use_lstm', 'lstm_cell_size', 'dim']
```

Comment: Good question. Related issue: https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/2538#issuecomment-409757506 where they recommend writing a custom model. I am still curious if this is possible to do via config though.